# IIS can't find NewtonSoft DLL

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have deployed several times a .NET Core application with success, but after adding a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, the application stopped working on the server (locally it runs ok). Does anyone have seen this kind of problem before?

Error message:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=3.1.8.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.

Raw exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=3.1.8.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
> find the file specified. File name:
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=3.1.8.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

- Approach 1: Copied this DLL and dependencies to `System32` and `System32\inetsrv`.
- Approach 2: Tried to register this DLL, but its not registerable.
- Approach 3: Added following tag to `web.config` to avoid shadow copy.
  `<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false"/>`

Comment: Have you tried to gac this dll?

Comment: Yes @tgolisch, this is second approach.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem, I had to generate again the deploy, and take the file "*.runtimeconfig" to the environment. After adding the reference, I didn't realize I had to get this file to the server too.

Comment: This answer saved me. Yes, I needed to add a reference to newtonsoft.json on the servers as well.  Makes sense because it is a different environment than the api itself which it was referencing.